# Neglecting mass at asymptotic spacelike momenta

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, renormalization

What is the rational/reason for neglecting masses at asymptotic non-exceptional space-like momenta. I have come across this as a first fix for being able to extract information from the Callan-symanzik and Gell-Mann-Low methods. Is it purely physical, or is it both physical and mathematically sound reason?

All responses are welcome.